# iOS 8.1.3 & Phonegap 2.9 Broken?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have an app built with phonegap 2.9 (using phonegap build) - The issue I have is that on some iOS devices (my own iPad mini had no issues for instance) once they update to iOS 8.1.3 my app no longer works (immediately closes) however a quick delete/reinstall seems to cure it.

My question is there something I can do to prevent this, for instance would it be worth the time to update to a new version of phonegap or is this something I can't really do anything about and will just have to hope my users have the patience to re-install?

Comment: You need to update to the latest build of phonegap for iOS 8.

Comment: Even if it actually works just fine without (albeit after a re-install)?

Comment: Yes, here is more information from the folks at Cordova: https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/cordova-ios-and-ios-8/